# How to test angular material dialog?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a custom dialog component class which I am trying to test. Specifically my close function which is this

```
  close(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

`dialogRef` is injected in that classes constructor as shown below

```
 constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  }
```

So my question would be, how could I mock `dialogRef` in my spec test file and test its close function?

My project is using angular 5, and angular material 5.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you are asking about testing components that use dialog and not dialog itself, In your test case, add

```
providers: [
     { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
     { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
 ]
```

That should provide neccessary dependencies.

Comment: No need to mock these providers, the correct way is as shown in angular source above

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to test this because the library you are using should already test its own component (which is not always the case).

But if you need a specific test which uses the close dialog reference, have a look at their test on this component which should help you write yours :

[https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/dialog/dialog.spec.ts#L186](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/05e6d076c3f0b350e5f6e8f3b5e17f102e485040/src/material/dialog/dialog.spec.ts#L186)

Comment: flush is the answer to all observables to execute thank you!